# How to do a WebView AND ListView in the same Activity onCreate()?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, webview

```
public class hello extends Activity, ListActivity {
    WebView main_webv;  
    ListView main_listv;
    public static final int REFRESHLIST_ID = Menu.FIRST;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private static final String SPLASH = "http://";
    private static final String LIST_NAMES = "http://";

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        main_webv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainwebview);
        main_webv.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        main_webv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        main_webv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        main_webv.addJavascriptInterface(new HelloJavascriptInterface(),"hello");
        main_webv.setWebChromeClient(new HelloWebChromeClient());
        main_webv.loadUrl(SPLASH);  
        main_webv.setVisibility( 4 );

        setContentView(R.layout.main_list);         
        main_listv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainlistview);    

    }
```

As you can see, I first create a webview.  Then, I want it to immediately disappear.  Then, I want the Listview to come up. But the problem is, I can't do Listview if I don't do ListActivity...but then I can't do Activity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the code I posted in your other (possibly related) thread: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235657/how-do-i-display-2-views-in-1-activity-android/2236284#2236284).
I am going to copy same code down:
This is my layout XML(weblister.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

Now, I create an Activity which will have both ListView and WebView in its View heirarchy but only one of them would be Visible:

```
public class WebAct extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.weblister);

            //setup listview
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                new String[]{"One","Two"}){

        });
            // setup web view
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

            // set visibility    
        listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can most certainly do a `ListView` without a `ListActivity`. You can also use a `WebView` with a `ListActivity`.

Comment: And Java doesnt allow multiple inheritance 
"so public class imhello extends Activity, ListActivity" is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

//main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/lister"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="300dp"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/webviewer"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="300dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/lister">    
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

//java file

```
package list.View;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //setup listview
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[]{"One","Two"}){

    });
        // setup web view
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

    //webview.loadUrl("www.google.com");

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "<img src=\"banner5.png\" height=\"98%\" width=\"100%\"/>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);



}
```

}